# PDF margin using PYQT5

Tags: pdf, pyqt5, pdf-generation

i am creating a PDF file with pyqt5, i would like to know how i can decrease the right margin.
For now my code formats the text to occupy the full line.

i wrote this loop to break the lines but the text gets badly formatted afterwards

```
painter.setFont(font_body)
            description_txt = self.ui.txtDescription.toPlainText()

            for pul in range(7):
                self.cursor.insertBlock()

            for text in [description_txt]:
                for letter in range(len(text)):
                    if letter == 42 or letter == 84 or letter == 126 or letter == 168 or letter == 210 or letter == 252 or letter == 294 or letter == 336 or letter == 378 or letter == 420 or letter == 462 or letter == 504 or letter == 546 or letter == 588 or letter == 630:
                        self.cursor.insertText('\n')
                    self.cursor.insertText(text[letter])
                self.cursor.insertText('\n')
```

This is my output

[image: The Main Window]

[image: PDF output]

if I remove the loops, the text lines are on top of the images

EDIT:
My printer, document and painter:

```
    self.printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.PrinterMode.HighResolution)
    self.printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    self.printer.setOutputFileName('relatorio.pdf')
    painter = QtGui.QPainter()
    painter.begin(self.printer)
        
    self.document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
    self.document.setDefaultFont(font_body)
 self.document.setPageSize(QtCore.QSizeF(self.printer.width(),self.printer.height())) 
         
    self.cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.document)
    self.cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

Comment: You certainly won't use the *character count* as a limit, since the font is not mono spaced. It's also unclear how you're adding the images. Why don't you just use a table? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante the images are not important for the context of the question, my question is how can I better format the imputed texts.

Comment: They are if you want to display them properly and, most importantly, if you want the text to consider them: you're using `setPageSize()` of the text to the *full* width of the printer size, and that's clearly not what you want: the width of the page size must consider the space you want to allocate to the text and images. QTextDocument will automatically wrap lines if the width is properly set, so you must not add new line characters on your own (and certainly not like that). If you want more precise help, provide a *valid* MRE (read that link more carefully).

Comment: You didn't want to answer my question directly, but even with your persistence I managed to solve my problem, indeed, the PageSize part was where I should change the value, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as my friend said in the comments of the post, a way to solve the text formatting is to remove this line break function and change the pagesize of "document".
the page size code would look like this:

```
self.document.setPageSize(QtCore.QSizeF(5000, self.printer.height()))
```

Change the value of 5000 to the value that best suits your needs.

to change height value, change `self.printer.height()` to some int value